# Java How to wait for task to finish before returning control

Tags: java, swing

This is a general question because i don't know what to search. But i have the following.

JPanel, put in some user information and press **FINISH** button, this goes to a JChooser to save the file. After they press save the program goes back to the JPanel and then closes. If there is a lot of user data, the JPanel will come back before the write is finished!

After they give a filename and press save, i want a progress/load bar to indicate the status of the save. How do i do this, how do it wait to finish the save before going back to the JPanel?

What is this called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do several things:

- First and foremost, do all the file writing and reading in a background thread so as not to freeze the Swing event thread. A SwingWorker would work well for this.
- If you need to display the progress of a long-running process being run in the SwingWorker, then update its progress property within its `doInBackground()` method as the process runs.
- Then add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker and listen for changes to this "bound" property. The property's name is "progress", so this should be easy.
- Then in the above listener, update the value of your JProgressBar.
- Next display the progress of the JProgressBar in a modal JDialog or JOptionPane (which is a variant of a modal JDialog). This will prevent the parent window from getting focus or running code until the dialog is no longer visible.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try to implement exactly that and ask if i get stuck =D